# Firebase Crashlytics non-fatal issue in main.jsbundle

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase

I have recently been receiving emails from Firebase Crashlytics reporting that issue detected in `main.jsbundle`. Screenshot as per below

[image]

However if I were to click into my app's Crashlytics, I can't find this issue in the issue lists at all. Even if I filtered out the specific build version, I still can't find it.

I'm only navigated to the stack trace below, while I click on the LEARN MORE button in crashlytics's email.

[image]

It's very different from rest issue reported by Crashlytics. Any idea what is this about?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using async/await or promise's chaining?
One of your promises is not catching exceptions.

Example for async/await:

```
try {
  const result = await doSomething();
  ....
} catch (error) {
  console.warn(error);
}
```

or chaining:

```
doSomething
  .then(e => {...})
  .finally(...)
  .catch(error => {...})
```